# Install Ubuntu Server 17 on Ryzen

Tags: linux-server, ubuntu-17.04, amd-ryzen

I got a Asus Prime B350 Plus motherboard an Ryzen 5 1400 processor, 16 Gb RAM (2400). I can start the installation and go all the way to the partitioner and when it starts to install the installation crashes.

What is up? Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Give any error messages? Maybe bad drive or install media?

Comment: Please [edit] and describe *how* the "installation crashes"... What happens exactly?

Answer (score -1):

There where my mistake... bad me. I tried to partition myself and must have made an error.
Using the whole disk - no problem.